# Is it safe to share my lightsail instance public static IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-lightsail

I wanted to save costs for my website launching for beginning stage. So I host my wordpress site at Lightsail. Then， I am using a S3 bucket to host static web and use the link from this bucket to redirect to the Lightsail public IP address. So that I will have at least a address with out just sharing IP address through my social media which unclickable in some platform.

May I know my practices is efficient enough or any better alternative. Is it unsafe to share out my instance IP address? If yes, what method can I use to improve the security of this method.

Comment: @Marcin Thks for your reply, I m clear on tat now. The only way is to buy a domain and set up ssl to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just share IP you will end up with most browsers blocking your calls to the instance. The reason is that all your connections will be conducted in **plain text** using http. This is **insecure** and thus usually will be blocked by browsers.

To make your website properly usable over internet you need to use **Https**, which requires valid [SSL certificate and your own domain](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-tls-ssl-certificates-in-lightsail-https).